# using Timer class - How can I make a scheduled Job started as scheduled even if the prior job isn't finished?

Tags: java, timer, scheduler

Without using Quartz, is there any option for Timer class or workaround to start scheduled jobs even if the previous job is not finished?

Here's sample code.

**Job Scheduled for every 1 sec**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UnitTest(timer), date.getTime(), 1000);
}
```

**Job Performed**

Each job has 2 second delay

```
public void run() {
    count++;
    int a = count; // to see which job is started and ended.
    System.out.println(this.now("HH:mm:ssSSS")+"- start "+count);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println(this.now("HH:mm:ssSSS")+"- end "+a);
}
```

**Result** - if the previous job is not finished, then the next job is not started.

```
12:14:21946 - start 1
12:14:23965 - end 1
12:14:23965 - start 2
12:14:25966 - end 2
12:14:25967 - start 3
12:14:27968 - end 3
12:14:27968 - start 4
12:14:29969 - end 4
12:14:29970 - start 5
12:14:31970 - end 5
12:14:31971 - start 6
12:14:33972 - end 6
```

How can I add this option for Timer class?

**Quartz - Concurrent Option** from http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

*By default, Quartz Jobs are stateless, resulting in the possibility of jobs interfering with each other. If you specify two triggers for the same JobDetail, it might be possible that before the first job has finished, the second one will start. If JobDetail classes implement the Stateful interface, this won't happen. The second job will not start before the first one has finished. To make jobs resulting from the MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean non-concurrent, set the concurrent flag to false.*

**EDITED SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class TEST01 {

Timer timerTEST01 = new Timer();

public String[] start()
{
    try
    {
        timerTEST01.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //DoWork
                    }
                };
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.start();
            }

        }, date.getTime(), 1000*60);

        return new String[]{"true", "Good Job!"};
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    finally{}
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of running the code directly at the timer, when the timer calls your method, spawn a new thread (or use a thread poll) to execute your task:

```
public void run() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            count++;
            int a = count; // to see which job is started and ended.
            System.out.println(this.now("HH:mm:ssSSS")+"- start "+count);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println(this.now("HH:mm:ssSSS")+"- end "+a);
        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}
```

This will guarantee that every single job executes at the given time even if the previous one hasn't executed.

Also, make sure your code works inside an anonymous inner class, that **count++** probably isn't going to work.

Comment: @handicop you also have to make sure that the code you are running in the tasks can deal with concurrency.

Comment: @Mauricio - Thank you. I added the full sample code above. This isn't a complete sample code since i need to fully control runnable somehow.

Comment: @handicop Your code is not thread safe: `count++` is not an atomic operation.  You should look into using an `AtomicInteger` for `count` instead of an `int`; it can then be incremented atomically.

Comment: What's missing now? The only thing I would change in your code is using an AtomicInteger as @toto2 said and instead of creating new threads using a static thread pool from **Executors.newCachedThreadPool()** ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool() )

Answer (score 0):

```
TimerTask timertask=new TimerTask(
    public void run(){
        //code
        }
    );

Timer timer = new Timer();
//Use timer to execute and set time limits for execution
```